# PHP - Printing variables stored as a string

Tags: php, string, variables

I've written the entire website in HTML and PHP but I ran into a small problem. After almost completing the website I was told to put all content in the database rather than just HTML. As I'm doing that I noticed that text with inline PHP variables doesn't get read when taken from the database.

Original Code:

```
<div>Hello <?php echo $World; ?></div>
```

New Code:

```
<div><?php getContent("title"); ?></div>
```

I have tried two ways of storing them in the database:
First method, text saved: `Hello <?php echo $World; ?>`
Which prints out `Hello` and ignores the variable.

Second method, text saved: `Hello $World`
Which prints out `Hello $World` instead of the value of `$World`

Other things I've tried:
`Hello $$World` - `Hello $$World`
`Hello {$World}` - `Hello {$World}`

Comment: So you think that every text taken from the database should be checked for variables presence? Really?

Comment: You can look into template packages like Smarty, or use placeholders and use str_replace to replace them. The much-maligned `eval` might also help you, but I cannot verify that.

Comment: omg, do not use `eval`!

Comment: "I was told to put all content in the database rather than just HTML" told by who? go tell them they are stupid.

Comment: Can you expand upon what variables you are `echo`ing in the middle of your content, are these variables from the database ? are they static? etc etc.

Comment: @cmorrissey Haha, I was waiting for someone to say that! Unfortunately, it was the first function I thought of.

Comment: You should probably be using some kind of template framework. You can't just put PHP code in a database.

Comment: If they want you to convert the website to a CMS, you should probably just use a CMS that already exists rather than trying to make your own. But depending on how complex your site already is, this conversion will not be a simple thing.

Comment: @u_mulder Yes, I have frequent texts such as product name, or company name that are saved as variables. I don't really see why you're surprised.
  
@aynber I like the `str_replace` idea, below it was suggested to use `sprintf` but that problematic because the whole point of putting all text in database is to be allow others to edit without editing html files.
  
@Dagon to clarify, I was told to make it for others to edit the data, and I figured database would be the easiest without editing html and risking breaking the site.

@cmorrissey they're from db but saved as global php variables.

Comment: @aynber if you'd write your solution as an answer, Ill mark it as the accepted solution. I tried doing it with `str_replace` and it works well, created a method that will search for all my variables and replace them, not too much changes to the code or the database. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use placeholders in your text, then use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to put replace the placeholders with your variables.

DB String:

```
<div>Hello WORLD_VAR</div>
```

And in the code:

```
$text = str_replace('WORLD_VAR', $World, $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about `sprintf`

`echo sprintf("Hello %s",$World);`

and store that `"Hello %s"` in the database  and use `$World`
like before.

If you implement it in the right way, you can make your website show in different languages.

But i thing you should more get into templating in php and/or use a template engine for php.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.sprintf.php

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template-Engine#Template-Engines_f.C3.BCr_PHP

And after the note in the comment:

The are many!! ways in 
php to do this
 `Hello <?php echo $World; ?>`
But in the end you only store real data in the database.
No php code or html just plain data. One of them can be templates like `Hello %s` other dynamic data like user names or whatever. And a template engine can help you to do that all in a proper way. (an templates are file-based, mostly)
Keep that in mind.

Comment: But what about other variables? He wants to store ALL the PHP content into the database.

Comment: Sry, that i twice hit `post` and wasn't really finished. :)

Comment: This is nice but the problem is that when someone else would edit the content, someone without programming experience, they would not be able to add their own variables or modify existing ones through the database, they will need to access the html files and risk breaking the site.